# JFreeChart using numeric query ORACLE

Tags: oracle, jfreechart, bar-chart

Good Evening!

I have a Table named SWIMMER, and need to find(in the NUMERIC field named TIME)the number of ocorrence of some values in a given interval(I am using Oracle10g).
I need to show something like that:

**23 higher or equal TIME       Shows HorizontalBar with value 300

22,3 higher or equal TIME minor or equal 23   Shows HorizontalBar with value 140

21,6 higher or equal TIME minor or equal 22,3 Shows HorizontalBar with value 15

20,9 higher or equal TIME minor or equal 21,6 Shows HorizontalBar with value 3**

Its possible to have a query to have a return like that?How could i assembly that query?
(Note: minor or equal are the Symbols,i can not post here because it is giving errors everytime)

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this ([Here is a sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02d93/8)):

```
select case 
           when time >= 23 then '23 =< TIME'
           when time < 23 and time >= 22.3 then '23 > TIME >= 22,3'
           when time < 22.3 and time >= 21.6 then '22,3 > TIME >= 21,6'
           when time < 21.6 and time >= 20.9 then '21,6 > TIME >= 20,9'
           else '20,9 > TIME'
        end   || ' with value '|| count(*) v
from your_table
group by case 
           when time >= 23 then '23 =< TIME'
           when time < 23 and time >= 22.3 then '23 > TIME >= 22,3'
           when time < 22.3 and time >= 21.6 then '22,3 > TIME >= 21,6'
           when time < 21.6 and time >= 20.9 then '21,6 > TIME >= 20,9'
           else '20,9 > TIME'
         end
```

and the results:

```
21,6 > TIME >= 20,9 with value 8 
20,9 > TIME with value 4 
22,3 > TIME >= 21,6 with value 6 
23 > TIME >= 22,3 with value 15 
23 =< TIME with value 66
```

---

**UPDATE:** As DavidAldrige suggested you can have a subquery:

```
select intrvl || ' with value '|| count(*) v
from
(select case 
           when time >= 23 then '23 =< TIME'
           when time < 23 and time >= 22.3 then '23 > TIME >= 22,3'
           when time < 22.3 and time >= 21.6 then '22,3 > TIME >= 21,6'
           when time < 21.6 and time >= 20.9 then '21,6 > TIME >= 20,9'
           else '20,9 > TIME'
        end   intrvl, time
from t)
group by intrvl
```

[And here is another demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02d93/11)

Comment: +1: I think I'd probably push the case into a subquery and aggregate on the result to avoid repeating that complex expression though.

Comment: A.B.Cade, thanks for your input!I will study your code and coment later!

Comment: David Aldridge, how i can use subqueries in that example?I just wrote the smallest portion of my problem to simplify the answers, but sometimes, i will have more than four-five expressions to show in the barchart(sometimes 10).Many thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer to include @DavidAldridge's suggestion