# JFreeChart using numeric query ORACLE ERROR

Tags: java, sql, swing, jfreechart, sqlexception

I was trying to make a query like in that topic: [JFreeChart using numeric query ORACLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050280/jfreechart-using-numeric-query-oracle)

to generate a barchart, but i am always receiving that error: **java.sql.SQLException: JDBCCategoryDataset.executeQuery() : insufficient columns returned from the database.**

My code is as follow:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TIME>23.73 AND TIME<=24.0 THEN '23.73<TIME<=24.10' 
    WHEN TIME>24.10 AND TIME<=25.68 THEN '24.10<TIME<=25.68'           
    WHEN TIME>25.68 AND TIME<=27.36 THEN '25.68<TIME<=27.36' 
        ELSE '27.36<TIME'  
   END   || ' with value '|| COUNT(*) v  FROM SWIMMER 
GROUP BY CASE 
WHEN TIME>23.73 AND TIME<=24.10 THEN '23.73<TIME<=24.10' 
WHEN TIME>24.10 AND TIME<=25.68 THEN '24.10<TIME<=25.68'  
WHEN TIME>25.68 AND TIME<=27.36 THEN '25.68<TIME<=27.36' 
ELSE '27.36<TIME'  END
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116455).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL you have quoted above results in an error (using [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/98324/8) to check the code) as the two case statements don't match JFreeChart is just re-throwing the error with a misleading message.

If your SQL is correct JFreeChart is telling you that you need additional columns in your result set as you are concatenating your case statement with the total your query, if it worked, would only return one column.

Try using this SQL:

```
SELECT time_range || ' with value ' || total as category, total
  FROM (SELECT time_range, COUNT(*) AS total
          FROM (SELECT CASE
                         WHEN TIME > 23.73
                              AND TIME <= 24.0 THEN
                          '23.73<TIME<=24.10'
                         WHEN TIME > 24.10
                              AND TIME <= 25.68 THEN
                          '24.10<TIME<=25.68'
                         WHEN TIME > 25.68
                              AND TIME <= 27.36 THEN
                          '25.68<TIME<=27.36'
                         ELSE
                          '27.36<TIME'
                       END AS time_range
                  FROM swimmer)
         GROUP BY time_range)
```

Comment: I tried that:

    SELECT intrvl || ' with value '|| count(*) v FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
    WHEN TIME>23.73 AND TIME<=24.0 THEN '23.73<TIME<=24.10' 
    WHEN TIME>24.10 AND TIME<=25.68 THEN '24.10<TIME<=25.68'           
    WHEN TIME>25.68 AND TIME<=27.36 THEN '25.68<TIME<=27.36' 
       ELSE '27.36<TIME'  
       END  intrvl, TIME FROM SWIMMER) 
    GROUP BY intrvl       copying that approach: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02d93/11   but did n work!

Comment: GrahamA, i need to simplify my query at max, because sometimes there is a hundred of intervals(i am showing only with four)!I will go crazy with many selects within selects!I got confused with your answer: why a need that many Alias?all the work in only one field in my DB(numeric field TIME)
Why my last didn t work?   Best Wishes,  PaulH.

Comment: @user2113983 your original query didn't work as you used 24.0 in the select and 24.10 in the group by. The one in your comment didn't work as you still only have one column I've corrected it [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02d93/13).  I used 3 in line queries (alias) so I didn't have to repeat the case statement - the code is [dry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Comment: GrahamA, thanks!That 24.0 was a mistyped when i made copyNpaste(its correct in original code), but you nailed:**select intrvl || ' with value '|| count(*) v, count(*) total** worked! But i have a minor problem: the text outside the chart is showing like that: 23.73<TIME<24.10 with value 23 , i wanna show just 23.73<TIME<24.10, i retired WITH VALUE, but whats the variable with the TOTAL?When i retired total, i got the same old error.I just wanna show the total in top of the bar, not in outside text. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Graham, i found it: 
    SELECT intrvl, count(*) total FROM       Thanks for your help!